# Saving site-wide settings

Tags: mysql, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

In my asp.net mvc4 application I allow the admin to change various site-wide such as site title, featured movies, categories, color schemes etc.

How do I save these changes? Should I create a row in the database including each setting as a column or?

And if so, each time I want to display the site I'll of course need the title of the site - will I then have to query the db every time to retrieve the title?

Comment: You can use session to store site title and other data which will be used over all pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible ways of doing this would be in a session or in the database as you suggested.

**Session:**
If this information is not to be persisted forever you could store it server side in a session. Depending on the policy you set the information would disappear after the user exits the browser which is probably not what you want.

**Database:**
You could store all the information in a single row per user (userId, settings). The settings could be stored as xml and so as a single string like so:

```
<settings>
    <title>...</title>
    <featuredmovies>
        <movie>...</movie>
    </featuredmovies>
    ...
</settings>
```

You will have to query the database but it is a very inexpensive query as you are only selecting based on the user id. You can also store the information in a session once you have retrieved it once and only update when the user changes their settings. This means every subsequent time you need the settings information you can get it from the session rather than the database which is very quick.

**Edit:** You would then parse the xml into your desired settings server side.